# React Hooks, useEffect unmount component issue

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, mqtt

good thursday people, I have the next code:

```
  const Variables = (props) => {

  const { activeVariable, mqttClient, updateRealTime } = props
  const [live] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (live && mqttClient) {

      // HERE I SUBSCRIBE TO TOPIC
      mqttClient.subscribe('variables_realtime')
      mqttClient.on('message', (topic, data) => {
        if (topic === 'variables_realtime') {
          const newData = JSON.parse(data.toString())
          console.log(topic, newData)
          updateRealTime(newData)
        }
      })
    }
    else mqttClient.unsubscribe('variables_realtime')

  }, [mqttClient, updateRealTime, live])

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // HERE I WANT TO UNSUBSCRIBE WHEN THE COMPONENT UNMOUNT 
      mqttClient.unsubscribe('variables_realtime')
    }
  }, [mqttClient])

  return (...)
}
```

So my problem is when I change to other route of react-router-dom, the UNSUBSCRIPTION happens but when I return to this Route, the subscription happen twice... I don't know why

Maybe I need to use the old react way with didMount, willUnmount, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your first effect needs to **return** the unsub function. You should not have two effects afaik. React will automatically unsub and resub as required, as the references to these `[mqttClient, updateRealTime, live]` change.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (live && mqttClient) {
      // HERE I SUBSCRIBE TO TOPIC
      mqttClient.subscribe('variables_realtime')
      mqttClient.on('message', (topic, data) => {
        if (topic === 'variables_realtime') {
          const newData = JSON.parse(data.toString())
          console.log(topic, newData)
          updateRealTime(newData)
        }
      })
    }

    return () => {
      // HERE I WANT TO UNSUBSCRIBE WHEN THE COMPONENT UNMOUNT 
      mqttClient.unsubscribe('variables_realtime')
    }

  }, [mqttClient, updateRealTime, live])
```

Comment: Yes, still not working (I change to another route and back again, and I get double subscription) but you have reason, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friends the problem here was the implementation with redux... So I need to pass the `mqtt.subscriptions` and `mqtt.on('message', (...) => {})` to my actions & reducers files of redux. Thanks!